# handle exception in foreach handling with XElements

Tags: c#

I have a foreach, iterating over an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.
At some time, it throws an exception
`System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.` (Translation: "The object reference was not set on an object instace")
I do parse a `XML DOM`, finding some specific nodes and try to analyse them.
Any ideas, how to avoid this?

This is my code:

```
var query = from p in dom.Descendants("meta")
                where (string)p.Attribute("name").Value == "custom.customer.ImageID" && p.Value != ""
                select p;

foreach (var el in query) 
{
    if (el is XElement && el.Value != null && el.Value != "") 
    {
        el.AddAfterSelf(this.getImageElement(el, "custom.customer.ImageUrl"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code for this as well. This is probably because of a null object somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have added some example code, sorry

Comment: Have you tried adding `&& el != null` after `el is XElement`?

Comment: At which point in your code you get this error ?

Comment: Hi, added a `&& el != null`, but it still throws an exception on the line ` foreach (var el in query) {`

Comment: Probably your `query` variable is null in that case, Put a breakpoint and check it in debugging mode.

Comment: You are likely trying to access a non-existent attribute in some cases - what happens if you add  `where el.Attribute("name") != null` into your query before `(string)p.Attribute("name")...`?

Comment: can you provide your xml?

Comment: So, the query is okay, lets assume that, okay? the exception is thrown in the foreach line, in debugger, it throws exacly when switching from one XElement to the next XElement, but the same XElement in other examples does run well.

Comment: Sry, i cannot give the XML, it is full of customer-specific stuff and we have a NDA for that :(

Comment: @SaschaPresnac, just a sample

Comment: @SaschaPresnac Linq queries are executed when the query is iterated, not when the query is created. So we cannot assume that the query is ok.

Comment: @SaschaPresnac _"So, the query is okay, lets assume that, okay?"_ No, why would we assume that? If the `foreach` line is throwing an exception then that would highly suggest that the problem is in the query.

Comment: **sidenote**: [Descendants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) return `IEnumerable<XElement>` so inside `foreach` you not need check it again: `el is XElement` always **true**, also a part of checking _Value_ you do in query, and part in `foreach`. Better move all checking inside query, also [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) is simple string, so you can use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) like `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of your `meta` elements lacks a `name` attribute, then this will throw a NullReferenceException:

```
p.Attribute("name").Value
```

You can cast XElements and XAttributes to strings to get their string value, and you can do that here to avoid an exception:

```
var query = from p in dom.Descendants("meta")
            where (string)p.Attribute("name") == "custom.customer.ImageID" && 
                  p.Value != ""
            select p;

foreach (var el in query) 
{
    if (el is XElement && el.Value != null && el.Value != "") 
    {
        el.AddAfterSelf(this.getImageElement(el, "custom.customer.ImageUrl"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I debugged the result and all elements are "hit" correctly by the query. It also iterates for some time then, in the middle of the foreach, it throws an exception in the foreach-line.

Comment: @SaschaPresnac Yes, I would expect that to happen if some of the elements have `name` attributes and some don't. Did you try my suggested change above or are you just assuming it's wrong without trying it?

Comment: That was it, you are completly right.
Changing the code made it and now, all went well.
I did not know that the LINQ is not executed once and the results are not fixed, even when debugger show something like that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to access a non-existent attribute. Change your code so that you're sure that the "name" attribute is not null:

```
var query = from p in dom.Descendants("meta")
                where p.Attribute("name") != null && (string)p.Attribute("name").Value == "custom.customer.ImageID" && p.Value != ""
                select p;
```

You should also evaluate if this is the best option or is this really just ignoring errors/deeper problems.

Judging by your comments, you should be aware that your specific Linq query is executed when you begin to iterate it (i.e. you're using deferred execution) - not when you create it. See [this](http://LINQ%20queries%20are%20always%20executed%20when%20the%20query%20variable%20is%20iterated%20over,%20not%20when%20the%20query%20variable%20is%20created.%20This%20is%20called%20deferred%20execution.) for details:

> In a query that returns a sequence of values, the query variable
>   itself never holds the query results and only stores the query
>   commands. Execution of the query is deferred until the query variable
>   is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop.